# Google Geocharts for Salesforce

Tags: visualforce, charts

Hi I am trying to setup google charts in visualforce page. In side I've created a report with the following id : 00O200000079q0Q

The code that I've created is below

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" />
    <apex:includeScript value="https://www.google.com/jsapi" />
    <script>
        google.load('visualization', '1', {
            'packages': ['geomap']
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax('/services/data/v31.0/analytics/reports/{!$CurrentPage.parameters.reportId}', {
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer {!$Api.Session_ID}');
                },
                success: function (reportResult) {
                    var chartPoints = [];
                    $.each(reportResult.groupingsDown.groupings, function (index, value) {
                        chartPoints.push([value.label, reportResult.factMap[value.key + "!T"].aggregates[0].value]);
                    });
                    var options = {};
                    var labels = [
                        ['Country', 'Metric']
                    ];
                    var myData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(labels.concat(chartPoints));
                    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoMap(document.getElementById('chart'));
                    chart.draw(myData, options);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div id="chart" height="500px" width="500px"></div>
</apex:page>
```

The issue that I have is that nothing is showing. The report has information for leads and what I want to show is the leads per country shown on the chart.

Also How can i connect the report with the code?

This is so interesting for me and I can't wait to see comments so I can make this possible.

Please advise,
Darko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. I will go in details and explain how you can manage to do this.

the code line:

```
 $.ajax('/services/data/v31.0/analytics/reports/{!$CurrentPage.parameters.reportId}',
```

Should represent the path to the report but you can change this to show direct path to the report with the following code:

```
$.ajax('/services/data/v31.0/analytics/reports/YourReportID',
```

where

> YourReportID

is the actual report ID that you want to place.

Or, optionally if you want the dashboard to show values to the many different reports see the code below.(group by country)

```
$.ajax('/services/data/v31.0/analytics/reports/{!$CurrentPage.parameters.Id}',
```

The second one for me was totally useless because I wanted to specify that specific report to show to the GeoChart Map.Also you need to parse the report id in the

> https://[yoursalesforce].salesforce.com/apex/[nameoftheVFpage]?id=[YourReportID]

Cheers,

Darko

Answer (score -1):

Follow this:

> http://coenraets.org/blog/2014/02/building-interactive-mobile-dashboards-for-the-salesforce-platform/

and enjoy.
Let'm me know if this help you.

Comment: A bit of explanation on why the linked page is applicable would be helpful.  It appears to be about mobile dashboards, not Google charts.  The question was about Google charts.